# Is it possible to hide keyboard while tapping UITextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

In my application I have to fill `UITextField` from the value exist in `UIPickerView` not through keyboard.

I have 2 `UITextFields`. In 1st textfield value is fetched from keyboard, and in 2nd textfield value is fetched from `UIPickerView`.

So, on tapping 2nd textfield I want to hide keyboard and show `UIPickerView`.

This is what I have done:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      [pickerToolBar setHidden:NO];//shows toolbar
        [pickerTime setHidden:NO];//shows UIPickerView
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

but after writing the above code the keyboard does not disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are populating the UITextField based on the UIPicker, why not simply disable user interaction with the UITextField? You can still put data there and the user will not be able to change it. To force the keyboard to stay hidden however, you can make the UITextField detect when it is touched/changed/etc and then have it resign first responder.

Comment: my UIPickerView should open on tapping UITextField.

Comment: Then under the option for willBeginEditing, have it bring up the UIPickerView and resign the first responder (get rid of keyboard).

Comment: "willBegingEditing" is this method for UITextfield?

Comment: Yes, it should be a built in method that identifies what is happening. In fact, there is a list of them here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: @BrianSachetta it may not be viable anymore, but I'm fairly sure I used that trick at some point when I was developing apps a few years ago. Keep in mind almost 6 years of iOS changes have now happened... I have no idea what works anymore. I need to start playing again. :)

Comment: Oh wow, didn't even look at the date ... 2011 ... what times :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try `UITextfield` delegate methods. put the following code in texfield `didBeginEditing` method.

```
[texfield resignfirstresonder];
```

Then the text field will block editing and keyboard will not appear.
Make sure you attached the text field delegate to the file owner.

Comment: additionally you can also invoke your UIpickerview show method in after you resign the responder of textfield. The code will look somhow like this:

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if(textfield == URTEXTFIELD)
{
 [textfield resignFirstResponder];
 [pickerview becomeFirstResponder];
}
}

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to hide the keyboard while the focus is inside the UITextField...

You must put UIPicker at a level where it does not get hidden behind the keyboard, so that it does not become an obstacle for you while selecting the value..

And if you're selecting value from UIPicker then why you need to tap in the UITextField, so if you're not tapping in the UiTextField, the keyboard will not be shown...

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

try with text field editable property as FALSE or user interaction enable property false and add one custom button with same size of your textfield with the button event of opening picker view.

Comment: i Think this is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
 gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;


- (void) hideKeyboard 
{
     [textfieldname1 resignFirstResponder];
     [textfieldname2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: when u entering some text on the textfield, it generates UITapGestureRecongnizer function. when u will leave it from textfield and clicking the view out of textfield, hideKeyboard function is fired. then the keyboard is hide.

Answer (score 1):

These answers might work but no one gave you the best answer; You can replace the keyboard view with the uipickerview when the textfield is tapped :)

```
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
field.inputView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
```